# save screenshot of page into folder using php

Tags: php, curl, screenshot

I wants to develop a project in which user has to enter url and then it will take screenshot of that application and then save the screenshot to a folder.
I am able to take screenshot but it is not saving into folder. i am getting error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: extension in C:\xampp\htdocs\curlproject.php on line 20

Warning: fopen(images-folder/Z.): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\curlproject.php on line 21
```

Here is code:

```
<?php
$websiteURL = $_POST["website"];
$api_response = 
file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/
v2/runPagespeed?url=$websiteURL&screenshot=true");

$result = json_decode($api_response, true);
//screenshot data
$screenshot = $result['screenshot']['data'];
$screenshot = str_replace(array('_','-'),array('/','+'),$screenshot); 
//display screenshot image
echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,".$screenshot."\" />";

$split_image = pathinfo($screenshot);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $screenshot);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 
5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C 
Safari/525.13");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$response= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$file_name = "images-
folder/".$split_image['filename'].".".$split_image['extension'];
$file = fopen($file_name , 'w') or die("X_x");
fwrite($file, $response);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: why not use phantom.js

Comment: can you show me how to do so

Comment: You say _but it is not saving into folder._ - what's happening / not happening? A good question on Stack Overflow has a _clearly defined problem statement_.  What is the problem, specifically?  And what research have you done, error(s) are generated, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can find to do in PHP...

iF I were you *I would have done it via javascript*

**Just for your knowledge** Use right tool for screen capture... ie. [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html)

here is a simple code to take screenshot

```
  var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open(url, function () {    // your URL
    page.render('D:/MySnapShotBox/saveAsSomeNome.png'); // can change location     
   });
```

Comment: You might make it clearer that this is _javascript_, not PHP (since question is tagged PHP, and not js).  Further, you should show how you get phantom JS loaded into this script / project in order to use it.  Further, what's `url` in your code?

Comment: OP has mentioned.... URL is an user input... i have given the link to phatom.js doc

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of error logging is it tells you exactly where to look for the problem.

```
Notice: Undefined index: extension in C:\xampp\htdocs\curlproject.php on line 20
```

On line 20 you have:

```
$file_name = "images-folder/".$split_image['filename'].".".$split_image['extension'];
```

So whatever should be setting `$split_image['extension']` obviously isn't doing anything.

Next up its:

```
Warning: fopen(images-folder/Z.): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\curlproject.php on line 21
```

Line 21 uses the filename constructed in line 20 and attempts to open a file:

```
$file = fopen($file_name , 'w') or die("X_x");
```

You need to fix your first issue first to get a valid file name, then you should use an absolute path to specify the directory and finally ensure the user account which your webserver is running as has write permissions in the directory.